# Ctrl +c and Backspace on Google Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, backspace, ctrl

I have an application in which I am listening for KeyPress events in an iFrame. On Google Chrome and IE, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and backspace never trigger the key press event. Backspace takes me to the previous page and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not captured at all.

Please let me know if there's any existing solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was listening on Keypress events, it turns out that on Chrome some of the events trigger through Keydown or Keyup events.

Comment: On safari, one needs to listen on KeyDown for capturing tab key.